# NodeJS - PDF generate from URL

Tags: node.js, pdf, url

Wanted to generate a PDF from a URL
(https://10.1.40.117/print/e71b7c0f-4ed1-4d0d-b868-87418d398a4a).
Please help me with the links which is used to do this using nodeJS

Comment: https://npms.io/search?q=pdf+url

Answer (score 0):

I use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to generate PDFs and their documentation has many examples. Since it uses Chrom(e|ium), it closes match my development environment as well which is nice when building the web pages.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might stumble on this question nowadays:

There is cool tool called [Gotenberg](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/) — Docker-powered stateless API for converting HTML, Markdown and Office documents to PDF. It supports converting URLs via Google Chrome headless.

And I am happen to be an author of JS/TS client for Gotenberg — [gotenberg-js-client](https://github.com/yumauri/gotenberg-js-client)

I welcome you to use it :)

**UPD**:
Gotenberg has new website now — https://gotenberg.dev